# Set up NTFS permissions to deny access to a user but allow one of their programs

Tags: windows-7, permissions, ntfs

Is it possible to set up NTFS permissions on a folder to deny access to a user, while allowing  a specific program running under their account to access it?

Specifically, user A is logged in as an Administrator, and runs a sync program (AeroFS) which needs to be able to sync user Z (non-admin) files. However, A should *not* be able to look through Z's files normally (I know an admin can take ownership anyway, but that's not the issue here).

Comment: What's preventing you from running AeroFS as the limited user instead? Without knowing more, that seems like the easier solution.

Comment: @Stephen The limited user is not logged often, but they still need their files in sync.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

There would be a possible solution if the sync application is using the SetBackupPrivilege and user A is in the BackupOperators group.
In that case the ntfs security will be bypassed for the backup.